# Why did "Open a pull request" remind occuer when I push to Github with some account in different PCs

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I was learning some new features about the Android JetPack and I init a repo on the Github to record my every step of the learning. I use some account push both in my home PC and work PC. This repo starts in my home PC but after I push a commit in work PC, my dev branch reminds me to "Open a pull request" and I'm totally confused. I browsed the commit history of dev branch, all come from one single account. I could really need some help to terminate this remind.

[open a pull request opration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNKOJ.png)

[pull request remind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM4w5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you push code to a non-default branch or to a fork, GitHub will suggest that you might want to open a pull request, regardless of the system or account you used.  It's common in many environments to share a single repository, and GitHub has no idea whether you're using a pull request workflow or not.  Since many users want to open a pull request in this case and use the UI to do so, it always opens a notification in the UI to suggest that.  There does not appear to be a way to turn this functionality off.

Comment: So, there is nothing I can do with this.

Comment: Correct.  There's no change you can make that will make it go away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess maybe I should migrate to the Gitlab.